# xlsx package saveWorkbook function

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I am using the below code

```
wb <- createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "sheet1")
addDataFrame(df, sheet1, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, startRow = 1)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "filename.xlsx")
```

I have already set the directory through R studio so need not to mention it explicitly.
I have gone through the documentation of write.xlsx which give an error commonly found on the web.
The issue is when I download and pen the workbook I see the data like this

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6
c(value1,value2,……) c(value1,value2,……) c(value1,value2,……) c(value1,value2,……) c(value1,value2,……) c(value1,value2,……)
```

I only find two rows, first row gives the column names and second row has all values of respective column in vector format (i.e. enclosed in c()). I do not want to row.names = TRUE as it would create an extra column with the row numbers.

same problem happens with write.xlsx2 function
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could improve the question. Please hover over the R tag - it asks for a minimal reproducible example. [Here's a guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). I suggest editing your posting accordingly. A good one usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data, code tries incl required packages - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session. *Why?* It makes it easier for all to follow and participate without guesswork. For example, what does `df` look like - nested lists?

Comment: `c(value1,value2,……)` often indicates that you got lists in your data frame columns as in e.g. `df <- data.frame(x=I(list(letters[1:2], LETTERS[1:2])), y=1:2)`

Comment: @lukeA Thank you for your help. I am using dplyr to process the data. I didnt realize class(df) from a dplyr shows "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame" When I use str(df) it did show data_frame properties in a list. However if I write data.frame(df) and then use it in saveWorkbook, it works fine as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the issue is during download. Rather it's during addDataFrame(). While adding your df, you will need to coerce your dataframe as a list. Example:

```
addDataFrame(list(df), sheet1, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, startRow = 1)
```